# Atomic variables - concurrent compare and swap vs load

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, tbb, compare-and-swap

I'm trying to implement a generic atomic array where threads can access concurrently indices to load / add values into. Currently, the data type of array items is double.

I'm using Intel TBB library (although it has the same behavior with the STL library). The operations that are causing problems are the load and add in parallel. See below how they are implemented:

```
T operator[] (const unsigned int idx) const
{        
    return arr[idx].load();
}    

void add(const int idx, const valuetype_t delta) 
{
    T current = 0;
    do 
    {
        current = arr[idx];
    } while (arr[idx].compare_and_swap(current + delta, current) != current);
}
```

I tried to add a mutex between concurrent add and load operations in the client code and it works perfectly. But without using mutex the results are wrong and it seems like load and compare and swap don't work properly in parallel ?!

Comment: Whats the actual issue you are seeing? (and also note that != for doubles is flaky when they've got NaN values but thats probably not your issue)

Comment: I get random huge values sometimes. For me it looks like some bytes are modified concurently despite the atomicity.

Comment: Perhaps there is a race on allocating or freeing the memory for the array?

Comment: The problem is somewhere else, not in the given pieces of code. Please share a test that allows to reproduce the issue - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve